# SolrCloud Commit Slow for Indexing One Document

Tags: java, solr, solrj, solrcloud

I am trying to use SolrJ to index one document to SolrCloud and query it. However, even if I am trying to index only one document, the commit is taking a really long time (10 minutes-ish to commit).

Here is my code and can anyone help me explain what is really going on here?

```
String zkHostString = "node1.datafireball.com:2181/solr";
SolrClient solr = new CloudSolrClient(zkHostString);
String mycollection = "mycollection";

java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();

// index document
SolrInputDocument document = new SolrInputDocument();
String myid = "myweirdid" + Long.toString(date.getTime());
document.addField("id", myid);
document.addField("mfr", "datafireball_mfr");
document.addField("mpn", "datafireball_mpn");
UpdateResponse indexResponse = solr.add(mycollection, document);
System.out.println(indexResponse);
solr.commit(mycollection);
System.out.println("------------");

// query index
SolrQuery query1 = new SolrQuery();
query1.set("q", "id:" + myid);
QueryResponse response1 = solr.query(mycollection, query1);
SolrDocumentList list1 = response1.getResults();
System.out.println(list1);
System.out.println("------------");
System.out.println("Done");
```

And the output looks like:

```
{responseHeader={status=0,QTime=411}}
```

And took a really really long time to print the `-------`, basically means the commit take a super long time.

Comment: Very likely you have some misconfiguration in your solrconfig.xml. You should also post it.

Comment: The QTime indicates how long the Solr server actually spent working with your query - are you sure you're not having DNS lookup/routing/etc. issues? Does a query against the same server with the same URL work instantly?